# Cloud Function is taking too long to send a message to PubSub

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

We are using Cloud Function to process images and sending a notification to PubSub once processing is complete. The function is built using nodejs 8 [beta]
Here's the snippet:

```
const PubSubMessage = require('@google-cloud/pubsub');
const pubsub = new PubSubMessage();
const htmlData = JSON.stringify({ url: url, html: Buffer.from(html).toString('base64') });
const htmlDataBuffer = Buffer.from(htmlData);
pubsub
  .topic("projects/<project-id>/topics/<name>")
  .publisher()
  .publish(htmlDataBuffer)
  .then(messageId => {
    console.log('Message ${messageId} published.');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('ERROR in sending to pubsub:', err);
    console.log('ERROR in sending to pubsub:', err);
  });
```

The message does get published to the PubSub queue, however, it is pushed ~90 seconds *after* the image processing is complete.

Any idea why pushing message to PubSub might be taking so long?

-anurag

Comment: How is your function being triggered?  Are you completing the function?  Could it be that the act of publishing a message is transactionally bounded such that it isn't actually transmitted until the function completes?  How are you determining that that there is a 90 second lag?

Comment: @Kolban
1. The function subscribes to a topic in PubSub.

2. The function is getting completed because I see the log line in StackDriver.

I see a 90-second lag on average by looking at the delta timestamp of last logline just before PubSub object is created and the timestamp when message gets pushed to PubSub.

Sorry about the bad formatting, still learning SO syntax.

Comment: To add more context, the original function is being triggered as a background function as per https://rominirani.com/google-cloud-functions-tutorial-writing-background-functions-e651f27ddde5

Comment: @Kolban after some more debugging, it's the same scenario when I try to send a HTTP request. Once background CloudFunction finishes execution, what's the best approach (sample code if possible) to let the system know that a particular event has happened?

Comment: What I'd suggest is attempt to pull the message from the subscription as soon as you call the function ... use gcloud pubsub subscriptions pull subscriptionName.  See if the message is actually present sooner than the log might let us think.  Perhaps logging is batched.

Comment: @Kolban - Tried it, the message doesn't exist in PubSub until after the log line arrives in StackDriver, implying logging isn't batched.

Comment: Any solution to this? I'm having the same issue. I launch a cloud function, that then publishes to pub sub - then 2 minutes later the stackdriver shows the pub sub function begins execution.

Comment: nope. no solution yet.

Comment: Are you actually sending messages to subscribers? Since I'm just using PubSub to run background functions, I have found a work around using only Cloud Functions. In my cloud function where I used to publish to PubSub, I now do a get request to my cloud functions index.js. That get request triggers a separate cloud function that creates data in my Firestore database. I use a promise ('.then()') with `res.end()` inside to ensure it finishes before ending. This way the first function (that made the get request), can perform a `res.send()` while the other function executes "in the background".